# Search among Lucene pre-indexing files using PHP?

Tags: java, php, indexing, solr, lucene

I have some large XML files (capacity about 50GB) and I first parse them and then I index them by Lucene in java. And now I have a directory of XML files and a directory of index files. And I can write our query and search among them using Java.

But now I want to search among pre-indexing files by PHP to display then in a web application, please help me How can I do these?

Comment: try to use solarium http://www.solarium-project.org/

Comment: So you have a Lucene index on disk that you want to search in PHP? Are you actually using Solr (as you've tagged the question as Solr), or are you just looking for a way to use the existing Lucene index files?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes I index my documets using Lucene and now I want to use them, I tagged solr because I know that for creating web interface I must using it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use solarium php libary.

> Solarium is a PHP Solr client library that accurately model Solr
>   concepts. Where many other Solr libraries only handle the
>   communication with Solr, Solarium also relieves you of handling all
>   the complex Solr query parameters using a well documented API.

http://www.solarium-project.org/

https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/blob/master/README.md